# SO reputation is different from MSO reputation

Tags: support, reputation

On Stack Overflow I have 585 reputation and on Meta Stack Overflow only 535. It's been like this for half an hour already.

As far as I know reputation, should be the same on both sites, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Caching.  Always caching.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the synchronization happens once every hour, so maybe you'll have to wait a little?

Comment: @Servy you beat me to that comment, you ruined my fun for the morning

Comment: @nKn The caches aren't nearly that long.  It should be on the order of minutes.

Comment: @Servy According to this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250889/2555451), it is once an hour for reputation updates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AFAIK, It takes few minutes almost one hour to update your reputation here. Don't worry wait for a while.

[What's Meta.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

Comment: Where did you get that quote? I was looking for that type of documentation.

Comment: Is it just me, or does anyone else find it ironic that a website for programmers uses an underlying process that needs to do 1960's style batch updates just to keep reputation in sync?