# Is negative rep on Meta taken into Consideration for a Question ban

Tags: support, meta, post-ban

After going through this post [SO reputation is different from MSO reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251194/so-reputation-is-different-from-mso-reputation) I have a question that does having Negative rep on meta contribute to the question/answer ban.

Ex:-
If I asked a question and get heavily down voted for the question.(Although having negative rep does not have any effect on rep ) Is this negative post also taken into consideration by the server to automatically block me from posting questions on SO.

Comment: There is no rep on meta...

Comment: related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265212/does-the-same-mechanism-for-an-automatic-question-ban-apply-on-mso?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> does having Negative rep on meta contribute to the question/answer ban

Um. What negative rep? Meta sites don't have reputation. At all. It is taken from the parent site. Always.

And you **can't** have less than 1 reputation. Ever.

> If I asked a question and get heavily down voted for the question.(Although having negative rep does not have any effect on rep ) Is this negative post also taken into consideration by the server to automatically block me from posting questions on SO.

No, it will not.