# Leaderboards Not Updating

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I am looking at my rank this week for gained reputation and I found something weird. It said that my reputation was 399, even though right now its is 433 (I have no idea why it is 418 here). I thought it was a bug, so I checked it later. Same thing happened. Why is my reputation change, rank, and total reputation not changing? Here is my current standings as of now : https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2014-12-28/4052384#4052384

Comment: You have earned 34 rep so far today. 433 - 34 = 399. Today's changes will be reflected in a few hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leaderboards only update once a day. Based on the following MSE answer, this happens at UTC 00:00:

[StackOverflow user leagues reputation doesn't match](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172819/stackoverflow-user-leagues-reputation-doesnt-match)

The reputation numbers shown on MSO are also delayed. I believe they update once every hour. Source:

[SO reputation is different from MSO reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251194/so-reputation-is-different-from-mso-reputation)

Even though that is probably not what you're seeing, there can also be a (typically small) difference between the league score and your reputation. The reason is that certain events, like the 1 rep point you lose when downvoting an answer, are not counted for the league score. Details:

[Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation)

Comment: Even after two days, the score is still the same.

Comment: @PythonMaster: no, you had 399 points at midnight UTC. You [gained 34 points so far today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4052384/pythonmaster?tab=reputation), giving you the score of 433 you have right now.

Comment: @PythonMaster: yesterday (UTC), your score in the rankings would have been 399 - 52 = 347.