# Bug reputation Stack Overflow meta and main site (More than 30 days & different devices)

Tags: bug, reputation

I just noticed that there's a bug in the reputation being shown incorrectly in the "Sites" menu (Same issue happening on Stack Overflow app for iOS).

I'm writing this question on my new work computer (this is my 3rd week) and my reputation hasn't changed much in the last 30 (actually 90 days), so, I don't believe it's a caching issue (I may be wrong), but according to this question: [SO reputation is different from MSO reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251194/so-reputation-is-different-from-mso-reputation) accepted answer:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

But it's not been synchronized for at least 30 days (more if we see my reputation history for the past 3 months at least).

In the second image you can see that I have my correct reputation in main site but not so on meta, third image shows my correct reputation on top, but not in the menu

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Sorry for the lack of handmade circles, I can't install many things in this computer :P

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317269/meta-sites-in-your-communities-display-different-reputation

Comment: Oh thanks @PikachuthePurpleWizard I always forget to check on MSE as well for some bugs like this one...

Comment: This probably stems from the fact that reputation is kept at meta sites, it just isn't used. So the number that displays needs to be updated from time to time. More than likely the sync for that custom addition to the list wasn't tracked.

Comment: I don't even think you should be seeing those in your site list. I only have the main sites without the meta and showing meta sites separately doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: I reproduced the bug by adding MSO into my communities as well. It displayed my reputation from 2 months ago - some time on 18 Feb to be specific.

Comment: Wait, there's an app? I'm getting this!

Comment: @ArtemisFowl there are 2, Stack Exchange & Stack Overflow apps :)

Answer (score 7):

Not so much an answer as confirmatory evidence that there's a problem, but it won't fit in a comment.  I did a screen grab with the drop down visible while looking at this question:

[image]

My MSO reputation shows with 5,599 difference from my main SO reputation.  AFAIK, I've not earned 5,000 reputation in the last hour.  I get essentially the same result when looking at a question on SO (rather than MSO) and using the drop-down.