# Why is my Meta Stack Overflow reputation different in the Stack Exchange sites menu?

Tags: bug, reputation, meta, users

I am curious... why is my Meta score different than my Stack Overflow score in the Stack Exchange Sites dropdown menu?  Is this a bug?  It's not out of sync for either of the site profile pages.

I've read that it takes a few minutes for the two scores to sync, and that the Meta score should be same as the SO score.  But it's been out of sync in the SE Sites menu for years now...

[image: SO and SO Meta reputation scores are different]

Comment: As you've found, these scores do often get out of sync due to caching, but they should eventually correct themselves, and, furthermore, they should be relatively *close* to one another, not thousands of points apart (unless, I suppose, you've recently given away a couple thousand points in the form of a bounty). So this does appear to be a bug. I have no further insight.

Comment: After further research, I think this is a known bug (just wasn't known to me, since I can't remember the last time I ever looked at a reputation counter); see [here on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382603) and [the main question on the global Meta, MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317269). As far as I can see, it goes back to a reputation recalculation that was done in 2019 to change the value of votes on questions, which was incomplete. Dunno why counting is so hard for the developers here...